# Synchronize on object

Tags: java

What is the problem in this case:

```
private static final Integer LOCK=0;
synchronized(LOCK){

//work
}
```

This is advised to be not a recommended monitor to lock on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This is advised to be not a recommended monitor to lock on.

```
private static final Integer LOCK=0;
```

is the same as

```
private static final Integer LOCK=Integer.valueOf(0);
```

and `Integer.valueOf(0)` is [cached by specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)).

What this means is that anybody else can also get `Integer.valueOf(0)` and synchronize on it; so you might get unexpected contention (at best) or deadlocks (at worst).

You can either use `new Integer(0)`, which is not a cached instance; or just use `new Object()`, since the fact it's an `Integer` is irrelevant if it is only used as a monitor.

Comment: I prefer `private static final Object LOCK = new Object();` in general. EDIT : Just like you just edit. We were synchronized here